# How to give react components dynamic ids, when React runs code twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's a [known React behavior](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) that code runs twice.

However, I'm creating a form builder in which I need to be able to give each form input a dynamic Id and use that Id for a lot of other purposes later. Here's a simple code of an input:

```
const Text = ({placeholder}) => {
    const [id, setId] = useState(Math.random());

    eventEmitter.on('global-event', () => {
       var field = document.querySelector(`#${id}`); // here, id is changed
    });
}
```

But since `Math.random()` is a side-effect, it's called twice and I can't create dynamic ids for my form fields.

The reason I'm using `document.querySelector` can be read [here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/trigger-input-updates-with-react-controlled-inputs).

My question is, how can I create consistent dynamic ids for my inputs?

Comment: use current time or uuid

Comment: @cybercoder, you mean something like `const [id, setId] = useState(new Date())`? That would result in the same problem.

Comment: Why not use a `ref` instead of `document.querySelector`? You won't need an `id` in that case.

Comment: `Math.random()` is only a "side-effect" if it doesn't return the same value on the second invocation (very likely). But even if it did return a different value, I don't see how that would be an issue in the limited scope of your snippet. Your event emitter shouldn't be in the body of the function component. This is where your issue lies since the function component body is also double-invoked in order to detect unintentional side-effects.

Comment: @DrewReese, React's state management is almost a hell. Very simple things to manage in a simple application across components quickly becomes so complicated and littered with boilerplate that we have suffered many times of failure using `Redux` and `React Context`. Therefore we decided to mix React with easy old-school stuff that we knew as a team. `EventEmitter` is one of them. It's a dynamic form builder, and everything is so dynamic that React fails to help.

Comment: On click of `submit` button, I need to send an event to all inputs (which are not known ahead of time, because they are created dynamically based on API and database) to validate themselves and if there is anything invalid, to stop form submission.

Comment: You've not spent enough time understanding the React component lifecycle I suspect. React state management is very simple, but if you fight it, you will have a hard and difficult time in Reactland. Have you tried moving the instantiation of the event emitter into a `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array (works likes `componentDidMount` and runs only once)?

Comment: @DrewReese, All I want is to be able to give my component a unique random Id. Is that illegal? Real-world is not academic contexts. Real-world means you should get the job done. A team of 6 people studied React lifecycle and context and state and failed and read Redux and failed again. Maybe we are stupid. But I would really appreciate it if you can help me in this case. I need a dynamic Id attribute.

Comment: [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) is a popular GUID generator, usage would be like `import { v4 as uuidV4} from 'uuid';` and `const [id] = useState(uuidV4());`. Note that I omitted the state updater since you likely won't want to update the id once generated. But maybe you do, in which case you'd `const [id, setId] = useState(uuidV4());` and call `setId(uuidV4())` to generate a new id and update state. I think you should also move the `eventEmitter.on` into an [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook with a dependency on the `id` state.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you think that `useState(Math.random());` is the side-effect causing you issue, but only functions passed to `useState` are double-invoked.

I think the issue you have is that the `eventEmitter.on` call is the unintentional side-effect since the function component body is also double invoked.

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - ***Function component bodies*** <-- this
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - ***Functions passed to `useState`***, `useMemo`, or `useReducer` <-- not this

To remedy this I believe you should place the `eventEmitter.on` logic into an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `id` state. You should also probably use `id` values that are guaranteed a lot more uniqueness. Don't forget to return a cleanup function from the effect to remove any active event "listeners", either when `id` updates, or when the component unmounts. This is to help clear out any resource leaks (*memory, sockets, etc...*).

Example:

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

const Text = ({placeholder}) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(uuidV4());

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      let field = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
    };

    eventEmitter.on('global-event', handler);

    return () => {
      eventEmitter.removeListener('global-event', handler);
    };
  }, [id]);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. If `Math.random()` is not the issue, then why do I get two values? You can see it in action [here](https://react-yjlkcs.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Of course, it's because `<React.StrictMode>` that won't bother in production. But I need to be able to get the same `id` in development mode too.

Comment: @HosseinFallah Right, I was just testing this all out in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-give-react-components-dynamic-ids-when-react-runs-code-twice-m5khv) as a sanity check. Interestingly enough, in React v17 I don't see the side-effects, but in React v16 I do. In the linked sandbox I show the side-effect and the non-side-effect in an `useEffect` hook so you can see the difference.

Comment: I saw the sandbox. But I fail to understand how it helps me. I'm using React `17.0.2` and I use `StrictMode` and I still receive two ids.

Comment: The point is, when inside that `useEffect` I want to retrive the element using `document.querySelector`, my code accesses the second `id`. While the `id={id}` has given my element the first `id`. Did you understand the problem?

Comment: @HosseinFallah If you are still seeing 2 ids then clearly you've still an unintentional side-effect somewhere. I've created a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-give-react-components-dynamic-ids-when-react-runs-code-twice-forked-nc0g8?file=/src/App.js) of the previously linked sandbox and attach the generated `id` state to an element and query the element by id within an `useEffect` hook. All the code within the effect hook sees just a single `id` while the console log side-effect in the function body sees two.

Comment: @HosseinFallah Perhaps it would be more productive if you could provide us a *running* example where you've applied correct React lifecycle patterns and yet still see an `id` discrepancy.